# Displaying a WooCommerce product via PHP

Tags: php, templates, plugins

Having a hard time composing a searchable query, so I apologize in advance if this has been covered.

I know you can add WooCommerce products to a page or post via short code, but I have one section of my site where it's displaying from theme settings and PHP template only.

So my question is, how can I display a product on this section via PHP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [do_shortcode()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode).

For example, in a template, if you were wanting to display products specifically by ID:

```
<?php

echo do_shortcode('[products ids="1, 2, 3, 4, 5"]');

?>
```

> WooCommerce comes with several shortcodes which can be used to insert
>   content inside posts and pages: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/
>
> You can add shortcodes to a post or page easily via the shortcode
>   shortcut button in the post editor: [image: Woo Commerce Shortcode Editor]